# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) 17.4.2 can't debug .Net Standard 2.0 Xamarin on Samsung Galaxy J5 2016 with Android 7.1.1

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging, android-7.1-nougat

I made that question to the Microsoft community months ago, the solution I came up with was to install the previous version of Visual Studio, 17.2.6, that could work with that phone. Then I got a new testing phone and I could debug on it just fine with any later Visual Studio version. But that old problem resurfaced when I tried to debug on my old phone again lately.

So, when I try to debug on the Samsung J5 I get the message that deployment is successful but debugging and the app stop. The app gets installed on the phone just fine, I can run it and test things, and for those parts that I would have added breakpoints I add temporary log entries to see what is happening. But debugging would be so much faster and easier. So I don't know what happened to Visual Studio 2022 after version 17.2.6 and the debugging on the J5 stopped working without changing the Android project's settings.

On to the output. The last lines of the Build output:

```
Found device: dbb6c608
Creating "obj\Debug\130\upload.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Creating directory "obj\.cache\".
Done building project "iService5.Droid.csproj".
Build succeeded.
2>Deployment was successful to Samsung SM-J510FN.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 02:07,822 ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 02:07,824 ==========
```

Last lines of Build Order output:

```
2>Starting deployment to Samsung SM-J510FN ...
2>Deploying to Samsung SM-J510FN ...
2>Deployment was successful to Samsung SM-J510FN.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 02:07,822 ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 02:07,824 ==========
```

On Debug output:

```
This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.
Forwarding debugger port 8815
Detecting existing process
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.bshg.iservice5.droid/crc649586142a72936f38.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.bshg.iservice5.droid/crc649586142a72936f38.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
```

The error I get in Xamarin Diagnostics window:

```
[E:]:                     Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger.LogError(String task, String format, Object[] args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidLogger.cs:line 63
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<RunShellCommandAsync>b__0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1012
[D:RunShellCommand]:      dbb6c608 setprop "debug.mono.extra" ""
-- Start SetProperty - 12/02/2022 13:15:16 (148.7124ms) --
[INPUT] setprop "debug.mono.extra" ""
[OUTPUT]

-- End SetProperty --
[D:RunShellCommand]:      dbb6c608 am force-stop com.bshg.iservice5.droid
-- Start ForceStop - 12/02/2022 13:15:16 (1794.4007ms) --
[INPUT] am force-stop com.bshg.iservice5.droid
[OUTPUT]

-- End ForceStop --
```

I have searched and searched and I can't find anything usefull. As for the configuration:
[Android Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXPWF.png)
[Advanced Android Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8z3Q.png)
Deleting bin and obj after testing different Android options made no difference. The same options debug on the new phone just fine. And I haven't changed the developers setting in the J5. They are the same ones that VS 17.2.6 could debug with.

I am currently installing 17.2.6 to exist in parallel with 17.4.2 on my pc to see if that will help. But any insights regarding the reason behind my problem would be greately appreciated!

Edit: Community is not available for versions before 17.2.10 anymore. So I'll try 17.2.10.

Edit 2: 17.2.10 debugs on my old phone just fine. Same settings, same everything. So, since our target android version is now 13 on the solution on latest vs, I also created a clone of the repo to work with on the old phone because older vs can have only up to android 12.1 as a target version.

Comment: Perhaps something corrupted or inconsistent at a low level, either in solutions `.vs` folder, or in something Xamarin installs on the phone for debugging. On the phone, manually delete the installed app, to be sure nothing is left behind. On the pc, delete `.vs` folder. Or to make sure VS doesn't have anything anywhere associated with the solution, make sure your source repository is up to date, then delete the solution folder completely and redownload (or download to a new empty folder).

Comment: The tooling is likely to be tested only against recent Android releases, so I don't believe you can work with Android 7 without issues (and no one is likely to fix that for you either). You can read Google's rule from https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/04/expanding-plays-target-level-api-requirements-to-strengthen-user-security.html